# Fit of data as a cos^2?

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, nonlinear-functions, trigonometry

I have collected this data of angles and intensities in lab to show Malus law so I have to fit the I as I=I0*cos^2(theta). I can't succeed with the cftool because it shows a curve totally different from my data, and I can't get a code that works. This is the data I got:
theta = [90, 110, 130, 135, 150, 170, 180, 190, 210, 225, 230, 250, 270, 290, 310,315,330, 350, 365,  370, 390]

I=  [0.0030, 0.6240, 1.3060, 1.3320, 0.9610, 0.1900, 0.0160, 0.1970, 1.1250, 1.3480, 1.2900, 0.5660, 0.0030, 0.5750, 1.6170, 1.6760, 1.0850, 0.1380, 0.0940,  0.2250, 1.2340]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: When I visually inspect a scatterplot of the data, there does not seem to be any clear trend or curve to be modeled.

Comment: If `theta` is in degrees, as it seems to be, then you need to use `cosd` rather than `cos`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried to code, but I couldn't get any near perfect match. I considered I0=1:

```
 figure;
 plot(theta, I)
 hold on;
 f = @(theta) cosd(theta)^2;
 fplot(f, [0, 400])
```